# How to use show second dropdown onchange of first dropdown using meteor.js?

Tags: meteor

I have two dropdowns in one row. I want to show second row consisting of two dropdowns which will appear onchange of first dropdown using jquery fadeIn() command in meteor.js?

Answer (score 0):

To make second dropdown visible on onchange of first dropdown,
you can do that in your template events properties.
using event properties you can bind functions to events (like jquery) which will get executed when binded event occurs.

Have a look at http://docs.meteor.com/#templates